# VideoJS add audioTrack source

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, video.js

what am trying to accomplish here , is having a video without audio , and two audio source for lets say , two different languages , without using `HLS/m3u8`, by adding the AudioTracks manually :

```
var video = videojs('l2e-video');

video.audioTracks().addTrack(
            [{
                label: 'audio-tracks-1',
                enabled: true,
                language: 'eng',
                kind: 'main',
                id: 'random',
            }, {
                label: 'audio-tracks-2',
                enabled: false,
                language: 'fr',
                kind: 'alternative',
                id: 'random',
            }]
        );
```

but the audio switching icon is not showing , I assume because there is no audio source , I have tried to append `uri/src` to the array am passing to `addTrack` , but it doesn't work , so how am I supposed to add a source for each `audioTrack`? or overall , how do I make it work?